# Change active Bootstrap menu item using html and css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to be able to change which menu item in is active depending on which file I am in. I include menu.html (the file below) in my three files: a.html, b.html and c.html.
How can I do this using only html and css? I use the Boostrap menu.
I basically want to change the menu item which is active according to the current file I am in.

```
<ul id="navbar_menu" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
            <li id="a"><a href="#">a</a></li>
            <li id="b"><a href="#">b</a></li>
            <li id="c"><a href="#">c</a></li>   
        </ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried my answer? That should do what you're asking if properly implemented.

Comment: I am not sure how set the list item to class="active" for the current page.

Comment: You don't need to define a active class, that will require JavaScript. But you can set the active state to the link for the current page. If you provide your code I can help you with the implementation.

Comment: What I want to achieve is that if page a is open then the li for a shall be active according to the code: <li id="a" class="active"><a href="#">a</a></li> Does that really require javascript? I like how the class active makes chosen list item look.

Comment: That is exactly how it works with the code I provided. Just add the css like I did in your stylesheet and the specific class to your body or wrapper like: <body class="a"> and then your second page <body class="b">, third: <body class="c">, the active button will be activated based on these styles.

Comment: What do I write to set the class to active? .a > li#a {
   /* Active Menu Style */ (class="active";)
}

Comment: No need to add an active "class" to the links to target it from CSS , leave the CSS like I provided and add a class to the parent div or body tag which is not in the PHP but the individual page.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding you're using PHP include for menu.

You can do this to automatically find the relevant menu to the current page:

In your 3 pages you add the "relevant class" to your div/section that is the wrapper:

```
<section class="a">
   <!-- your php include for menu-->
</section>
```

Second page:

```
<section class="b">
   <!-- your php include for menu-->
</section>
```

Third page:

```
<section class="c">
   <!-- your php include for menu-->
</section>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.a > li#a {
   /* Active Menu Style */
}
.b > li#b {
   /* Active Menu Style */
}
.c > li#c {
   /* Active Menu Style */
}
```

This will enable the menu for the current page with your php include file:

```
<ul>
    <li id="a"><a href="#">a</a></li>
    <li id="b"><a href="#">b</a></li>
    <li id="c"><a href="#">c</a></li>   
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct you should make an active class and added it to the actual active list-item.